# Minecraft mod communicating with BuildCraft

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I am making a industrial mod to minecraft, and I don't know if my machines could work with kinesis pipes (or any other power source). My machines will be powered by mj. But how can I link BuildCraft or any other mod to my mod, so I can use their power sources to my machines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to do. I used the OreDictionary to "link" items, and Thermal Expansion's API for my machines so they could consume power. The `@Optional.Interface` annotation can also implement a interface, when the interface can be undefined (if the mod for that interface isn't installed).

Answer (score 0):

To really link with any mod, you can just add it to your build path/dependencies 
and then do imports like any other class with your IDE.

It's also a good idea to look at its source code so you actually know what to do via decompiling it. A good website for this is http://javadecompilers.com

Comment: How does buildcraft and thermal expansion do to communicate with each other?